# Need a framework suggession

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc

I am using Java Script MVC framework for building a Web Application.. Now i want the same application for mobile aswell..

Can some of you suggest me the best Framework(light) to convert my application for mobile and touch devices?

Raviteja Avvari

Comment: Too broad...do you want to build a mobile-optimized web version, or a native app, and for what platforms/form-factors?

Comment: which framework are you using now?

Comment: @DmitryB http://www.javascriptmvc.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what did you try? Did you look at JQuery Mobile? http://jquerymobile.com/ it's quite nice.
You could even combine it with KnockoutJS, look at this post for more info: [How to architecture a webapp using jquery-mobile and knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089727/how-to-architecture-a-webapp-using-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 1):

We use a couple of frameworks for our mobile web dev:

1. Twitter Bootstrap : Great if you want to build one solution that scales to mobile (use the fluid layout, and make sure to enable mobile)
2. jQuery Mobile : A little more app-like. jQuery Mobile is great if you follow their rules, but hard to effectively style without a lot of customization. We just use this for prototyping
3. Dashcode / Apple : Great for iPhone web apps. This platform is all visual and has smooth, easy-to-use data integration and animations

4*. PhoneGap : Not really a javascript framework, but this is a great way to translate a simple web-app into a packaged app for several platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch API is very similar to ExtJS.
Porting will be easier as the frameworks are very similar in API, class structures and overall architecture.