# Modifying jquery mobile theme for iOS, android and windows phone 8 native look

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, themes

I am developing a phone gap application using jquery mobile. I need to have a native look and feel for 3 different platform. windows phone 8, iPhone and android. What is the way to proceed. Should i create 3 different set of html pages for all three platform [ since navigation model is different, header and footers are different for different phone]. Is there a way i can create single html page and change the theme based on mobile phone.. Is jquery mobile a right choice for theme customization. I will be grateful if you suggest approach for the same... are there predefined themes exist for the same..

Comment: Personally, I'd build each interface natively and create an API to my web service (if there is one), or learn the basics of each OS stack to develop my logic natively too. JQM looks like crap, and styling it to fit each phone will likely make it look worse

Comment: Thanks Bojangles...  but i need to build a single cross platform application using html5/js/css3... we cant build native application for each platform.. what the best possible approach to match the native look and feel. jquery mobile gives themeroller to create separate theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to switch between different css during html loading via simple javascript code.

Other recommendations

1.
The good way to have configurable options across platforms is to store them in app.json and then load them during app start via XmlHttpRequest and apply (so you have differen app.json for iOS, Android, WP). The simple app.json could look like the following

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "js": ["platformspecific.js", "platformspecific.2js"],
  "css": ["platformspecific.css", "platformspecific2.css"],
  "settings": {
     "isOption1Enabled": true,
     "isOption2Enabled": false
  } 
}
```

2.
Take a look on mvvm approach using KnockoutJS
[How to architecture a webapp using jquery-mobile and knockoutjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089727/how-to-architecture-a-webapp-using-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs)

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/10/integrating-knockout-and-jquerymobile/

3.
For Windows Phone take a look https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability/Demo-jQuery-Mobile-theme-for-Windows-Phone-8

4.
Take a look on Sencha Touch as an alternative approach. It is much more powerful when it comes to customizations for different platforms